# Installing packages in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, tflite, flutterflow

I have installed `tflite_flutter` to my custom widget but it keeps throwing errors, I went through the documentation and added in `tflite_flutter:^0.10.2` as per the documentation but I still face some custom errors.

[image: The issue that I am facing]

Code for my app:

```dart
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class Model extends StatefulWidget {
  const Model({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  _ModelState createState() => _ModelState();
}

class _ModelState extends State<Model> {
  late Interpreter _interpreter;
  Uint8List outputData = Uint8List.fromList(List<int>.filled(256 * 256 * 3, 0));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel();
  }

  Future<void> loadModel() async {
    _interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('model.tflite');
  }

  Future<Uint8List> makePrediction(List<double> inputData) async {
    // Run inference
    List<List<double>> outputData =
        List.filled(1, List.filled(256 * 256 * 3, 0.0));
    _interpreter.run(inputData, outputData);

    // Process output
    List<int> pixels = outputData[0].map((value) => value.round()).toList();

    // Convert pixels to Uint8List
    Uint8List imageBytes = Uint8List.fromList(pixels);

    return imageBytes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.memory(outputData, width: 256, height: 256);
  }
}
```